# True Type Font File

Tags: c

I am working on Scalable font. I wanted to know the specification of .ttf file or contains of .ttf file and how these contains are arranged.
Question- Does anybody knows about the basic structure of .ttf file.

How to see the contains of .ttf binary file.

Answer (score 6):

The FontForge documentation has links to all of the relevant font standards. Note that there is no one-true-TrueType standard.

http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/bibliography.html#Formats

Microsoft's Standard: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/SpecificationsOverview.mspx

Adobe's OpenType Standard (an extension to normal TrueType): http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype.html

Apple's Standard: http://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/ (complete in retro-2002 web)

Note that FontForge its self is a good reference implementation.

Comment: Thanks.will I get structure of <<times.ttf>> file?